# Flash - Auto-scrolling text areas

Tags: flash

Greetings!

I'm creating a Flash game...blackjack, actually. It uses a back-end made from Java.
Anyway, there's a basic chat in the game, where new messages are added to the bottom...pretty much your standard chat window.

This is how I do it now:
txtArea.verticalScrollPosition = txtArea.maxVerticalScrollPosition;

However, that does not always work. Sometimes it does, sometimes it doesn't (oddly enough). I'm looking for a permanent solution. txtArea is the component TextArea (d'uh), and I'm using ActionScript 2.0.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Yours,
Shane~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out the problem, I apparently wasn't using the correct code and I have no idea why. I think I found what I was using on Google...
Anyway, anyone else who happens to suffer with this should note it's this instead:

```
txtArea.vPosition = txtArea.maxVPosition;
```

Thank you for your time.

Yours,
Shane~

Answer (score 0):

You might try trimming the text (removing whitespace, extra new lines, etc. from the end of the string) before setting the vertical position. Also I think cropping the text to enough characters that is guaranteed to fill the screen and then using the `textHeight` property would give much more control on the positioning.